# how to disable "choose wallpaper from" prompt in KitKat?

Tags: wallpaper

I have a new Acer tablet running v. 4.4.4 No Wallpaper (black) is selected , and I use this device for e-reading. The prompt to "select wallpaper from" constantly pops up and is an irritant. Can it be disabled?

Answer (score 1):

Download and set this as your wallpaper and see if the problem persists.

[image: Black Wallpaper]

Comment: I just see a black square. Nothing to download. If this is another black background to use as wallpaper, I already have the "no wallpaper" ap installed , and it does not deactivate the prompt.

Comment: you need to save this pic or get a black wallpaper and use it as wallpaper instead of using an app.